# Only some output of git is processed when piped to sed

Tags: bash, git, shell, sed

I want to add a tag before each line of the output of `git checkout` command.

```
www [master] % git checkout master --progress | sed -e "s/^/[tag] -- /"
Already on 'master'
[tag] -- Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

As the output content above, the first line `Already on 'master'` cannot be prefixed with `[tag] --`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In unix, by default, all processes are granted two already open streams through which they may send output--standard output, and standard error--and another stream where they may receive input--standard input.  You can think of these as files that are already open and available before the process starts.

The idea is that programs should send output that may be processed by some other program to the standard output and (more relevant to this example) any errors or helpful diagnostics should be sent to standard error.  If a program is designed to filter data, it should read that data from the standard input.

In shell, the pipe (`|`) operator can be used to connect the standard output of the command to its left to the standard input of the command to its right.  In your example, you have connected the standard output of `git` to the standard input of `sed`.  This is why some of `git`'s output is prefixed.

The unprefixed data was emitted by `git` via its standard error stream.

In order to also filter `git`'s standard error stream, you must first tell your shell to connect this stream to wherever the standard output stream goes, by running it as follows:

```
git checkout master --progress 2>&1
```

When this is piped to `sed`:

```
git checkout master --progress 2>&1 | sed -e "s/^/[tag] -- /"
```

...all of `git`s output will be prefixed.

For more information on `2>&1`, run `man bash` and search for the **REDIRECTION** section.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with `awk` then could try following. If I get it correctly you want to add tag string only to lines which do not have string master in them, if this is the case try following.

```
your_command |  awk '!/master/{$0="[tag]" OFS $0} 1'
```